# Is there a way to install Homebrew into a docker container on an ARM Mac

Tags: docker, macos, arm, homebrew, vscode-devcontainer

Working with a client and we have a mix of Windows, ARM Macs, and AMD Macs in the dev team.  I am trying to get a .devcontainer configured for the project to improve portability and reduce onboarding effort.  I have a container that works on the Windows machines and AMD Macs, but fails on the ARM Macs when trying to install homebrew into the container.  The container build fails with this message:
`Homebrew on Linux is not supported on ARM processors`

This is a minimalist dockerfile that replicates the issue:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.9
RUN curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh >> /tmp/install-homebrew.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/install-homebrew.sh
RUN NONINTERACTIVE=1 /bin/bash -c /tmp/install-homebrew.sh
RUN rm /tmp/install-homebrew.sh
```

Is there a way to get this container to run on each of the noted architectures?  Unfortunately the client has some significant dependencies on `brew` commands baked into their processes (make files etc) and it seems unlikely that we will get them to change in that respect, so "don't use homebrew in the container" is probably not a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting the question I came across one potential answer.  Modifying the docker file to specify the platform as AMD gets the ARM macs to run it in an emulation mode and seems to get things working so far.  Biggest concern at the moment is the potential performance impact from using the emulator.

In short, modify the first line of the docker file to include a platform argument:
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.9`